# How to set up SwiftUI toolbar to display in the center of the view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-toolbar

I am experimenting with SwiftUI ToolbarItem in various positions in my view, such as in bottomBar and navigation. I am wondering if it is possible to center the ToolBarItem vertically in the view, as opposed to the top or bottom. When setting up the placement for ToolBarItem, I am not seeing a placement property for centering. Any idea how this ToolBarItem could be centered in the view?

Here is my code for the ToolBarItem, currently set to .bottomBar:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cityName = ""
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack() {
                //some content
            }.navigationTitle("Weather")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Enter City Name", text: $cityName)
                            .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 150, maxWidth: 240, minHeight: 30, idealHeight: 40, maxHeight: 50, alignment: .leading)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            // some action
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "plus")
                                    .font(.title)
                            }
                            .padding(15)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .cornerRadius(40)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to center the system toolbar vertically? It's a system component meant to be used and displayed at the bottom of the screen. If you want something in the center of the screen, you shouldn't be using a toolbar...

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach for placing your toolbar elements in the middle of the `ContentView`.

It should look exactly like the `.toolbar {...}` you have, and it functions exactly as you expect.
The main difference with this approach is that
you can put the toolbar anywhere you like.
You can also use `GeometryReader` for very fine placement in your view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cityName = ""
    
    var toolbar: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            TextField("Enter City Name", text: $cityName)
                .frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 110, maxWidth: 140, minHeight: 30, idealHeight: 40, maxHeight: 50, alignment: .leading)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "plus").font(.title)
                .padding(15)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(40)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                toolbar
                Spacer()
            }.navigationTitle("Weather")
        }
    }
}
```